# Why double comparison not working with if condition?

Tags: c#, .net

please see my below code and double comparison not working properly, though i have cast, double.Equal() method used, but no result. giving false

```
double b;
b = (1.6 + 1.6 + 1.6) / 3.0;

if( b == 1.6d)
{
     Console.WriteLine("True");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("False");
}

// if( b.Equal(1.6))  -- No Result
```

Comment: This is a common problem with double comparisons  This is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: An option would be to change your `double` to `decimal` if you're open too that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because actual result value of operation `(1.6 + 1.6 + 1.6) / 3.0` is `1.6000000000000003`.

You need to use like:

```
if(Math.Abs(1.6d - value) < TOLERANCE)
{
     Console.WriteLine("True");
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine("False");
}
```

And define acceptable tolerance.

Have a look at [0.30000000000000004.com](http://0.30000000000000004.com/)

Comment: Any reason for downvotes?

Comment: This explains why the if statement fails, but misses the more interesting question of why the operation is mathematically inaccurate.

Comment: @BJMyers, the question was why condition fails. And I was about to provide a link to explanation.